# Adding a pre-existing 2.0.6 Cassandra cluster to a 4.1.2 OpsCenter gets a timeout

Tags: configuration, datastax, cassandra-2.0, opscenter

I have a three node Cassandra cluster with nodes at 10.3.10.129, 10.3.10.130, and 10.3.10.131.  The cluster has a pre-existing keyspace with data.  opscenter-agents have been installed on all three nodes.  Trying to add the pre-existing cluster via one (or all) of the nodes using the OpsCenter web page, I get an error message: "Error creating cluster. Timeout while adding cluster.  Please check the log for details on the problem."

How does one avoid these timeouts?

The log shows that connection to the three nodes has been achieved.  There is an additional warning message in opscenterd.log: "WARN: ProcessingError while calling CreateClusterConfController: Timeout while adding cluster. Please check the log for details on the problem."

The Cassandra version is 2.0.6.  The DataStax OpsCenter version is 4.1.2.  The release notes claims that there 4.1.2 fixes Cassandra 2.0 bugs, so it looks like OpsCenter does support the version of Cassandra that I am using.

```
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 []  INFO: Starting new cluster services for Layer8Demo
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Starting services for cluster Layer8Demo
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Loading event plugins
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Loading event plugin conf /etc/opscenter/event-plugins/posturl.conf
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Successfully loaded event plugin conf /etc/opscenter/event-plugins/posturl.conf
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Loading event plugin conf /etc/opscenter/event-plugins/email.conf
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Successfully loaded event plugin conf /etc/opscenter/event-plugins/email.conf
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Done loading event plugins
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 []  INFO: Metric caching enabled with 50 points and 1000 metrics cached
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 []  INFO: Starting PushService
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Starting CassandraCluster service
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: agent_config items: {'cassandra_log_location': '/var/log/cassandra/system.log', 'thrift_port': 9160, 'thrift_ssl_truststore': None, 'rollups300_ttl': 2419200, 'rollups86400_ttl': -1, 'jmx_port': 7199, 'metrics_ignored_solr_cores': '', 'api_port': '61621', 'metrics_enabled': 1, 'thrift_ssl_truststore_type': 'JKS', 'kerberos_use_ticket_cache': True, 'use_ssl': 0, 'kerberos_renew_tgt': True, 'rollups60_ttl': 604800, 'cassandra_install_location': '', 'rollups7200_ttl': 31536000, 'kerberos_debug': False, 'storage_keyspace': 'OpsCenter', 'ec2_metadata_api_host': '169.254.169.254', 'provisioning': 0, 'kerberos_use_keytab': True, 'metrics_ignored_column_families': '', 'thrift_ssl_truststore_password': None, 'metrics_ignored_keyspaces': 'system, system_traces, system_auth, dse_auth, OpsCenter'}
2014-04-15 21:15:27+0000 []  INFO: Stopping factory <opscenterd.ThriftService.NoReconnectCassandraClientFactory instance at 0x225af80>
2014-04-15 21:15:29+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Enterprise functionality: False
2014-04-15 21:15:29+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.PropertyFileSnitch
2014-04-15 21:15:29+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
2014-04-15 21:15:29+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Cluster Name: Layer8Demo
2014-04-15 21:15:31+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Recognizing new node 10.3.10.130 ('4124999021280409113')
2014-04-15 21:15:31+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Node 10.3.10.130 has multiple tokens (vnodes). Only one picked for display.
2014-04-15 21:15:31+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Recognizing new node 10.3.10.129 ('1364620421069081446')
2014-04-15 21:15:31+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Node 10.3.10.129 has multiple tokens (vnodes). Only one picked for display.
2014-04-15 21:15:31+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Recognizing new node 10.3.10.131 ('6921776330201546034')
2014-04-15 21:15:31+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Node 10.3.10.131 has multiple tokens (vnodes). Only one picked for display.
2014-04-15 21:15:42+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Keyspaces: {'xs': CassandraKeyspace(name=xs, column_families=[], tables=[u'threat_morph', u'con_hit', u'session_event', u'threat_undo_morph', u'ip_alert', u'session_alert', u'url_table', u'session_event_morph', u'threat', u'con_hit_morph', u'session_end_morph'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'DC1': '2'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy'}), 'system': CassandraKeyspace(name=system, column_families=['IndexInfo', 'NodeIdInfo', 'schema_keyspaces', 'hints'], tables=[u'peers', u'range_xfers', u'schema_keyspaces', u'schema_columns', u'IndexInfo', u'schema_triggers', u'sstable_activity', u'peer_events', u'paxos', u'batchlog', u'NodeIdInfo', u'compaction_history', u'compactions_in_progress', u'schema_columnfamilies', u'local', u'hints'], attributes={'strategy_options': {}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}), 'OpsCenter': CassandraKeyspace(name=OpsCenter, column_families=['events_timeline', 'settings', 'rollups60', 'rollups86400', 'pdps', 'rollups7200', 'events', 'rollups300'], tables=[u'events_timeline', u'settings', u'rollups60', u'rollups86400', u'pdps', u'rollups7200', u'events', u'rollups300'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'replication_factor': '2'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'}), 'system_traces': CassandraKeyspace(name=system_traces, column_families=[], tables=[u'events', u'sessions'], attributes={'strategy_options': {'replication_factor': '2'}, 'replica_placement_strategy': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'})}
2014-04-15 21:15:47+0000 []  WARN: ProcessingError while calling CreateClusterConfController: Timeout while adding cluster. Please check the log for details on the problem.
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Initializing event storage.
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Persisting config to Cassandra for agent on 10.3.10.130
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Attempting to load all persisted alert rules
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Done initializing event storage.
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Done loading persisted scheduled job descriptions
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Done loading persisted alert rules
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Persisting config to Cassandra for agent on 10.3.10.131
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Persisting config to Cassandra for agent on 10.3.10.129
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: OpsCenter starting up.
2014-04-15 21:17:06+0000 [Layer8Demo]  INFO: Stopping repair service
```

The startup log for datastax-agent confirms the connection has been made.

```
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,116 Loading conf files: /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,188 Java vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_51
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,265 Default config values: {:rollups300_ttl 2419200, :settings_cf "settings", :my_channel_prefix "/agent", :poll_period 60, :kerberos_hostname nil, :storage_dc nil, :thrift_conn_timeout 10000, :thrift_max_frame_size 15728640, :rollups60_ttl 604800, :stomp_port 61620, :shorttime_interval 10, :longtime_interval 300, :private-conf-props ["initial_token" "listen_address" "broadcast_address" "rpc_address"], :thrift_port 9160, :async_retry_timeout 5, :agent-conf-group "global-cluster-agent-group", :jmx_host "127.0.0.1", :ec2_metadata_api_host "169.254.169.254", :metrics_enabled 1, :async_queue_size 5000, :autodiscovery_interval 120, :rollups7200_ttl 31536000, :autodiscovery_enabled true, :thrift_ssl_truststore nil, :rollup_snapshot_period 300, :is_package true, :monitor_command "/usr/share/datastax-agent/bin/datastax_agent_monitor", INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,116 Loading conf files: /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,188 Java vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_51
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,265 Default config values: {:rollups300_ttl 2419200, :settings_cf "settings", :my_channel_prefix "/agent", :poll_period 60, :kerberos_hostname nil, :storage_dc nil, :thrift_conn_timeout 100 :thrift_socket_timeout 5000, :cassandra_log_location "/var/log/cassandra/system.log", :jmx_port 7199, :jmx_metrics_threadpool_size 4, :use_ssl 0, :rollups86400_ttl -1, :nodedetails_threadpool_size 3, :api_port 61621, :kerberos_service nil, :kerberos_client_principal nil, :jmx_thread_pool_size 5, :production 1, :runs_sudo 1, :stomp_interface "10.1.3.33", :storage_keyspace "OpsCenter", :rollup_snapshot_threshold 300, :thrift_ssl_truststore_type "JKS", :realtime_interval 5}
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,266 Waiting for the config from OpsCenter
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,268 Attempting to determine Cassandra's broadcast address through JMX
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,269 Starting Stomp
 INFO [Initialization] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,270 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,274 SSL communication is disabled
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,274 Creating stomp connection to 10.1.3.33:61620
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,288 Reconnecting in 0s.
 INFO [main] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,323 Starting Jetty server: {:port 61621, :host nil, :ssl? false, :join? false}
 INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2014-04-15 20:41:06,605 Connected to 10.1.3.33:61620
```

Comment: It looks like the error in version 4.1.0 "Definition file updates don't work with Python 2.6" has reappeared in 4.1.2.  I'll back up to version 4.1.1 and report back.

Comment: The timeout you mentioned shouldn't be related to the definition file bug, but it is something we have seen before that is usually resolved Cassandra side. I'll look into this and the other cases to see if there's something OpsCenter can do to fix and/or improve the handling of those cases.  I'm also verifying that the definition file update bug cannot be reproduced, so if you have more information as to why you think it's back, please share. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same error, with all the same versions of the datastax library. Running in EC2 on Ubuntu 12.04 (so python 2.6 couldn't be the problem for me).  I was able to get a test cluster connected, but now am stuck for what I want to be the production cluster.  I have everything in puppet, so I'm going to tear it down and try again.

Comment: It started working after fiddling with the security group. I have a single group with the opscenterd instance and all cassandra instances, and I opened ports 22 and 443 to the group (I have https turned on for opscenterd). In the example [security group settings](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMISecurityGroup.html) those are world-accessible so it's not clear if they are needed by cassandra or not. It's also possible I just got lucky and it started working unrelated to the change I made. :shrug: